# realtime consume data from kafka to clickhouse

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, clickhouse

I have many ipfix(netflow) records which inserted in the Kafka and I have created consumer via go language with this code
package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
//  "os"
//  "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
       "github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go"
    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"
    cluster "github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster"
)

type options struct {
    Broker  string
    Topic   string
    Debug   bool
    Workers int
}

type dataField struct {
    I int
    V interface{}
}
type Header struct {
    Version     int 
    Length      int 
    ExportTime  int64 
    SequenceNo  int 
    DomainID    int 
}

type ipfix struct {
    AgentID  string
        Header  Header 
    DataSets [][]dataField
}

type dIPFIXSample struct {
    device string
    sourceIPv4Address    string
    sourceTransportPort   uint64 
    postNATSourceIPv4Address    string
    postNATSourceTransportPort uint64
    destinationIPv4Address string
    postNATDestinationIPv4Address string
    postNATDestinationTransportPort uint64
    dstport   uint64 
       timestamp  string 
       postNATSourceIPv6Address string
       postNATDestinationIPv6Address string
      sourceIPv6Address string
      destinationIPv6Address string
      proto  uint8
     login string
     sessionid  uint64 
}

var opts options

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&opts.Broker, "broker", "172.18.0.4:9092", "broker ipaddress:port")
    flag.StringVar(&opts.Topic, "topic", "vflow.ipfix", "kafka topic")
    flag.BoolVar(&opts.Debug, "debug", true, "enabled/disabled debug")
    flag.IntVar(&opts.Workers, "workers", 16, "workers number / partition number")

    flag.Parse()
}


func main() {
    var (
        wg sync.WaitGroup
        ch = make(chan ipfix, 10000)
    )

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go ingestClickHouse(ch)
    }

    wg.Add(opts.Workers)

    for i := 0; i < opts.Workers; i++ {
        go func(ti int) {
            // create a new kafka reader with the broker and topic
            r := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
                Brokers: []string{opts.Broker},
                Topic:   opts.Topic,
                GroupID: "mygroup",
                // start consuming from the earliest message
                StartOffset: 0,
            })

            pCount := 0
            count := 0
            tik := time.Tick(10 * time.Second)

            for {
                select {
                case <-tik:
                    if opts.Debug {
                        log.Printf("partition GroupId#%d,  rate=%d\n", ti, (count-pCount)/10)
                    }
                    pCount = count
                default:
                    // read the next message from kafka
                    m, err := r.ReadMessage(context.Background())
                    if err != nil {
                        if err == kafka.ErrGenerationEnded {
                            log.Println("generation ended")
                            return
                        }
                        log.Println(err)
                        continue
                    }
//                  log.Printf("Received message from Kafka: %s\n", string(m.Value))

                                        
                    // unmarshal the message into an ipfix struct
                     objmap:=  ipfix{}
                    if err := json.Unmarshal(m.Value, &objmap); err != nil {
                        log.Println(err)
                        continue
                    }
                                           fmt.Sprintf("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk%v",objmap);
                    // send the ipfix struct to the ingestClickHouse goroutine
                    ch <- objmap
//                                         go ingestClickHouse(ch)

                    // mark the message as processed
                    if err := r.CommitMessages(context.Background(), m); err != nil {
                        log.Println(err)
                        continue
                    }

                    count++
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
//  close(ch)
}


func ingestClickHouse(ch chan ipfix) {
    var sample ipfix

    connect, err := sql.Open("clickhouse", "tcp://127.0.0.1:9000?debug=true&username=default&password=wawa123")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := connect.Ping(); err != nil {
        if exception, ok := err.(*clickhouse.Exception); ok {
            log.Printf("[%d] %s \n%s\n", exception.Code, exception.Message, exception.StackTrace)
        } else {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        return
    }
    defer connect.Close()
    for {
        tx, err := connect.Begin()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        stmt, err := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO natdb.natlogs (timestamp,router_ip,sourceIPv4Address, sourceTransportPort,postNATSourceIPv4Address,postNATSourceTransportPort,destinationIPv4Address,dstport,postNATDestinationIPv4Address, postNATDestinationTransportPort,postNATSourceIPv6Address,postNATDestinationIPv6Address,sourceIPv6Address,destinationIPv6Address,proto,login) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }


        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {

            sample = <-ch
            for _, data := range sample.DataSets {
                s := dIPFIXSample{}
                for _, dd := range data {
                    switch dd.I {
                    case 8:
                        s.sourceIPv4Address = dd.V.(string)
                    case 7:
                        s.sourceTransportPort =uint64( dd.V.(float64))
                    case 225:
                        s.postNATSourceIPv4Address =  dd.V.(string)
                    case 227:
                        s.postNATSourceTransportPort = uint64(dd.V.(float64))
                    case 12:
                          s.destinationIPv4Address=dd.V.(string)
                    case 11:
                          s.dstport=uint64(dd.V.(float64))
                    case 226:
                          s.postNATDestinationIPv4Address=dd.V.(string)
                    case 27:
                          s.sourceIPv6Address=dd.V.(string)
                    case 28:
                          s.destinationIPv6Address=dd.V.(string)
                    case 281:
                          s.postNATSourceIPv6Address=dd.V.(string)
                    case 282:
                          s.postNATDestinationIPv6Address=dd.V.(string) 
                    case 2003:
                          s.login =dd.V.(string)
                          log.Printf(dd.V.(string))   
                    case 228:
                          s.postNATDestinationTransportPort=uint64(dd.V.(float64))                      
                    case 4:
                        s.proto = uint8(dd.V.(float64))
                    }
                }
                timestamp := time.Unix(sample.Header.ExportTime, 0).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")


 

                if _, err := stmt.Exec(
 
                    timestamp,
                     
                    sample.AgentID,
                    s.sourceIPv4Address,
                    s.sourceTransportPort,
                    s.postNATSourceIPv4Address,
                    s.postNATSourceTransportPort,
                    s.destinationIPv4Address,
                    s.dstport,
                    s.postNATDestinationIPv4Address,
                    s.postNATDestinationTransportPort,
                                        s.postNATSourceIPv6Address,
                                        s.postNATDestinationIPv6Address,
                                        s.sourceIPv6Address,
                                        s.destinationIPv6Address,
                    s.proto,
                                        s.login,
                ); err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

}



     }
        go func(tx *sql.Tx) {
            if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }(tx)


    }
}
```

the code is working fine and I am able to insert data in clickhouse but because of high traffics and huge amount of data which inserted in Kafka there is a delay between Kafka and clickhouse which increase as the traffic increased , right now I have more than 20 hours delay, can you please recommend me any way to make it faster this is my clickhouse table

```
CREATE TABLE natdb.natlogs
(
    `timestamp` DateTime,
    `router_ip` String,
    `sourceIPv4Address` String,
    `sourceTransportPort` UInt64,
    `postNATSourceIPv4Address` String,
    `postNATSourceTransportPort` UInt64,
    `destinationIPv4Address` String,
    `dstport` UInt64,
    `postNATDestinationIPv4Address` String,
    `postNATDestinationTransportPort` UInt64,
    `proto` UInt8,
    `login` String,
    `sessionid` String,
    `sourceIPv6Address` String,
    `destinationIPv6Address` String,
    `postNATSourceIPv6Address` String,
    `postNATDestinationIPv6Address` String,
    INDEX idx_natlogs_router_source_time_postnat (router_ip, sourceIPv4Address, timestamp, postNATSourceIPv4Address) TYPE minmax GRANULARITY 1
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(timestamp)
ORDER BY router_ip
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I want to have faster way to insert data in clickhouse
thanks in advance

I tried go consumer and it is  working  fine to  insert data , it can  insert more than  2Millions records  in 5 min  ,  but the problem is  the data that entering  kafka  in every  5 min is  more than 20 Millions  records  ,  so  there is  a big delay  between  both kafka and clickhouse

Comment: look to https://github.com/akvorado/akvorado and try to figure out with sources how it works in this project

Comment: did you try native Clickhouse Kafka engine? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka. There is also good collection of info about that https://altinity.com/blog/2020-5-21-clickhouse-kafka-engine-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research  , I created  partitions on my  kafka  topic ,  which  make the consumer working faster , now  I  am  able to hare real time data in clickhouse I  just applied this command in kafka  and it is worked like a  charm

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --topic vflow.ipfix --partitions 16
```